# How to create css file form sass file in the same directory

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

I am learning SASS. I am using VS Code as my code editor. I have installed `Live SASS Compiler` extension to compile SASS file.

I have created a folder. In this folder I have multiple folders. I want to create css file in each folder not main folder.

Check the image:
[image]

In SCSS folder there is a folder named "Partials-and-Imports". I want to create the css folder in the "Partials-and-Imports" folder not in main folder(CSS) because I have to create multiple folders in the main folder.

How can I do that?

Comment: why do you define this setting in the GLOBAL settings, it is clearly workspace related, define it in `.vscode/settings.json`

Comment: Look into build tools like webpack or similar, you have much more options there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy and past this block of code in your sass compiler setting - Set your exported CSS Styles, Formats & save location - :)

```json
  "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [

    {
      "format": "expanded",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../css/"
    }
  ]
```